# How to insert markup into a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table row with four cells. I'm trying to use javascript to insert this:

```
</tr><tr>
```

in between two cells which would basically create two rows from one (at certain screen sizes).

I need to change this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

into this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td> 
    </tr><tr>       
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my script:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(3)').before('</tr><tr>');
```

And here is what I get:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td> 
    <tr></tr>            <--- notice that </tr><tr> becomes <tr></tr>!
        <td>stuff</td>        
        <td>stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The tags are appearing in the right place, but they are switched around!

What the heck is going on here? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another row and transfer the last two `td` elements to the new row.

```
$('<tr>').insertAfter('tr').append($('td').slice(-2))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9xnsus5/2/

Answer (score 1):

Despite the abstraction offered by jQuery, you are not working with HTML. You are working with DOM objects.

`"</tr><tr>"` gets interpreted as:

1. End tag for table row which doesn't exist, ignore this
2. Create a table row

You need to create a table row, put it where you want it to be and then move the table cells into it.

Possibly like this:

```
var tr = $('<tr />');
tr.append($('td+td+td'));
$('table').append(tr);
```